# why doesn't use-package :defines stop this "variable is void" error?

Tags: use-package, variables

Error (use-package): w3m/:config: Symbol’s value as variable is void: w3m-filter-configuration

I have a use-package statement that was producing an error because apparently emacs-w3m doesn't configure its variables at the times other packages do. Anyway, my question is, why do I have to resort to `setq-default` here, when my reading of the use-package help is that the `:defines` keyword was made for precisely this use-case?

```lisp
(use-package w3m
  :demand t
  :defines w3m-filter-configuration ;; doesn't seem to do any good
  :config
  (setq-default w3m-filter-configuration (list)) ;; why is this line needed despite :defines?
  (add-to-list 'w3m-filter-configuration '(t "Make page readable" ".*" tsa/readability)))
```

Comment: I think you need `:config` there not `:custom`.

Comment: Thanks, @FranBurstall. It was a typo when I cut out the unnecessary parts of the real definition. Fixed now.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Comments deleted and close-vote retracted.